# Damaged solder pads on FX-Audio DAC-X6 Alternate solder locations?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, audio, repair, pinout

I've tried to remove a faulty 6.5mm headphone jack from a FX-Audio DAC-X6 and ended up removing the solder pads from the board. I'm trying to save this instead of trashing it and buying a new one for $50+. If I order a new headphone socket where can I attach the pins (Right, Left, Ground)? I don't understand what the 4th pin is and where it should be attached.

[image: top of board]

[image: back of board]

[image: replacement headphone port]

[image: top full image]

Comment: Most likely is a make brake signal pin

Comment: Being typically pedantic, it's not a 6.5mm jack, it's 6.35mm or 1/4 inch. Similarly the jack often called an 1/8 inch jack in the USA is in fact 3.5mm. So there !

Comment: Can't you 'patch' the board up ?

The damage doesn't look that severe.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the traces from each damaged pad and connect a wire between that pin and the other end of the trace.

If it's a TRS jack (and not TRRS), the extra pin may just be for mounting (mechanical) and not need to connect anywhere electrically. It could also be a switched contact. You can figure that out with a continuity meter.

Be aware that this PCB likely has a ground plane which means that any pad that's supposed to connect to ground may not have a visible trace. Check continuity between those pads and a point you know is grounded to be sure.

Next time, be more careful about desoldering before you pull the component out. A desoldering iron with a vacuum pump will come in handy for that type of work.

And when you order the new part, make sure the footprint and pinout matches perfectly. Check the measurements on the datasheet to be sure it will fit properly.

Comment: The only trace I can see is on the back of the board [marked in green](https://i.imgur.com/dl1ITyk.jpg)

Comment: I see a trace on the top side of the board that leads under what appears to be a relay. Check continuity between nearby pads and find where it's supposed to connect.

Comment: Yeah the trace you see on the top of the board is the same trace on the bottom that I marked in green.

Comment: They are 2 different traces coming from 2 different pads. Look closer. The tip and ring of the jack are likely going to 2 different pins of the relay. There would be no reason to put the same connection on the top and bottom layers of the board.

Comment: [Ah you are right!](https://i.imgur.com/neGkU2Y.jpg) Now for that middle, seems like it doesn't connect to anything, is it possible that it's just extra support for the connector to the board?

Comment: I can't say for sure, could be the sleeve (ground) or it could be a switched contact. Did you check continuity between what's left of that pad and ground? If you know the part number of the jack or have a datasheet, you can easily figure out what that pin's supposed to do.

Comment: It's also possible that it's supposed to be a switched contact but wasn't used in this design. It could also be a switched contact tied to ground so that the jack is grounded when you unplug the connector. I would definitely check continuity between that point and ground though.

Comment: The issue with me trying to check that location is that there doesn't seem to be any traces going to it. I scratched the soldermask around the hole and it's just ground everywhere around it (top & bottom of board). The original headphone socket looked exactly like the picture posted above, 4 pin. I thought that was weird since there are also 3 pin sockets for sale in the exact same footprint and style. I will solder 3 wires, 2 top locations, 1 to a known ground and then see if headphones work correctly when the board is powered on.

Comment: That means that pin is likely connected to the ground plane so try connecting it to ground. That should work fine. You might only need 3 out of those 4 pins connected to get any audio, just T, R, and S.

Comment: If you plug a cable into the jack, you can easily check continuity between each contact of the other end of the cable and each pin on the jack. That way you know for sure which is T R and S, which is all you need. If you unplug the cable, you might find that that 4th pin connects to another pin (switched). You may want to leave it open or ground it depending on what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I just soldered 3 wires, L/R/ground and touched them to a 1/4 plug connected to headphones, everything is working. Now I need to order a replacement 6.5mm socket. Since it doesn't seem that a fourth connection is needed can I order a 3 pin or should I just get a 4 pin like the original to be safe?

Comment: You might be able to get away with it with just 3 pins, or that 4th pin might be doing something in the background that you're unaware of. I don't know enough about your device to say. It would be safer to replace it with the original component connected to the same places. But if you aren't having any issues with just 3 pins, maybe you're okay.

Comment: Come to think of it, what symptoms did you see that led you to believe the headphone jack was faulty?

Comment: Sometimes the audio would only play out of one headphone speaker. When I jiggled the socket on the amp it would correct the issue. However do to movement while wearing headphones the issue would happen again. This why I attempted to unsolder the socket and replace it. I've also tried other known working headphones to make sure it wasn't the headphones causing the issue.